# special character in URL

Tags: javascript, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

I'm trying to open a OneNote file from Google Chrome, my URI has a German character (ä,ß).
After clicking on the link, its open the OneNote but it shows an error message that The specified location cannot be opened by OneNote, and that's because the URI is still encoded.

Im using React framework so My Code looks like:

```
JS: let link ='onenote:///O:\\DWH OneNote\\DWH Team\\A - Regelmäßige Auswertungen\\3 - Monatsstatistiken'.
link = encodeURI(link)
JSX: <a href={link}>OneNote</a>
```

the same code works in Firefox and in IE.

the error message in OneNote shows that (ä and ß) characters are still encoded

```
'onenote:O:\DWH OneNote\DWH Team\A - Regelm%C3%A4%C3%9Fige Auswertungen\3 - Monatsstatistiken\M0002.1'
```

Chrom DevTools:
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMYKY.jpg)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHu22.jpg)

Comment: You will have to encode the characters in the exact charset that your file system uses to represent those characters; which may not be a trivial thing to figure out.

Comment: @vlaz `encodeURI` is not deprecated. You might be thinking about `escape`.

Comment: Is the link exactly the same in FF and Chrome when you are looking at the HTML in DevConsole ?

Comment: Does it work with `Regelm%E4%DFige` by any chance …?

Comment: @NikKyriakides I have already treid, but it didn't wrok.

Comment: @IVOGELOV it is exactly the same.

Comment: @04FS No it didn't work.

Comment: Since your HTML page defines the encoding as UTF-8 (at least with META tag, if not by an HTTP header) - have you tried to leave the link unencoded ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV I have treid leaving the URI as it is without encoding it. It did work in Firefox but not in Chrome!

Comment: Just to make sure your server does not mess with the encoding header - can you create a simple HTML file locally on your computer and put both an encoded and unencoded version of the link there. Then open the file from your computer in FF and Chrome and check.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I have just did what you suggested, but I got the same problem. it worked in FF but not in Chrome!

Comment: Can you check in Firefox dev tools as well, what the request looks like in there? Maybe that helps figuring out where the encoding might be handled differently.

Comment: @04FS FF send no request !

Comment: Hm, yeah, it’s actually handing off handling of the link to an external handler registered for that protocol, so that’s probably not going to show up in dev tools.